# Unable to create Package for QField

Tags: qgis, qfieldsync

The "Package for QField" option is inactive. It's my first project I want to transfer to QField. I'm using 3.16.11-Hannover on a Mac OS HighSierra and QField Sync 3.4.4.

[image]

Comment: layer config is required first https://qfield.org/docs/synchronise/qfieldsync.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to choose Configure Current Project.
The settings you choose there determine how Qfield packages up your project. For instance, you might not want all the layers in your QGIS project to be uploaded to your mobile project.

Answer (score 0):

For me it appeared after setting my project to work with QField Cloud. Maybe you will find this helpful: https://www.opengis.ch/2022/03/05/qfield-users-sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-storage-access-on-android/